# BIRT Conditional Datasources

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT version 3.7.1.

I have two data Sources (D1 , D2), each one of which is connected to a few datasets (D1: setA, setB, setC and D2: setE, setF). The two data Sources lead to different databases and only one will be used at a time.

Does anybody know if I could somehow check which of the data Sources has found a connection and then use only the related datasets? I would assume that there is a function that returns null when a data Source fails to connect. However I did not managed to find such a method.

If there is one, assuming that D1 did not manage to connect, is it possible to cancel the associated datasets setA, setB, setC and off course hide the tables that use them?? Or am I going to have a huge exception at the end of my report?